# Metaphorical meaning of ゴミの分別

Tags: meaning, nouns, sports, subjects, metaphor

Context: Riku is a young boxer in Baba's gym. Yanagi, an older boxer, used to be in Baba's gym too in the past, but he moved to another gym because he was not satisfied with Baba's methods. The two, Riku and Yanagi, are now talking about Baba.

> Yanagi: 駒としてしか選手を見れない人だ。キミも抱えてる不満一つや二つじゃ済まないだろ？
>
> Riku: **ゴミの分別**をしてもらいたいです…ね。昔から会長はそうだったんですか？

First of all, I am not sure about the meaning of 一つや二つじゃ済まない, but I guess that Yanagi is saying that Riku too is not satisfied. Then, the literal meaning of ゴミの分別 is "garbage sorting", but I can't really imagine how it could fit the context, so I guess it was used with a metaphorical meaning that I was not able to find on dictionaries. Also, I am not sure about the subject of してもらいたい, is it Riku or Baba?

[Here you can see](https://i.imgur.com/cjUQOBX.jpg) the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 一つ(や二つ)では済まない, literally "(listing) one or two won't suffice", is a set phrase that effectively means "there are quite a few".
- Assuming ゴミの分別 is used for the first time in this page, it is **not** a common metaphor for something. It just means "separation/sorting of garbage" here. ゴミの分別をしてもらいたいです is "I (=Riku) want him (=Baba) to sort garbage", implying that's the main complaint about Baba. That is, Riku euphemistically denied Yanagi's speculation and implied he was basically satisfied with his environment.